# Removing item from list using a class method

Tags: c#, class

I have 2 classes "Ooievaar" (a stork) and "Kikker" (Frog). Now what I'm trying to do is have a stork eat a frog. The way i thought I could do this is by removing a random frog from a list in my main code using the "eetkikker" method, but I have no idea how to do this. any tips would help!

Ooievaar Class(Stork)

```
 class Ooievaar : Dier
    {
        private int GegetenKikkers;

        public Ooievaar(string naam, string geslacht, int leeftijd, int gegetenKikkers) : base(naam, geslacht, leeftijd)
        {
            GegetenKikkers = gegetenKikkers;
        }

        public void EetKikker(Kikker kikker)
        {

        }
    }
```

Kikker Class (frog)

```
class Kikker : Dier
    {
        public Kikker(string Naamdier, string GeslachtDier, int Leeftijd) : base(Naamdier, GeslachtDier, Leeftijd)
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Mijn naam is {Naam} de eend en ik ben een {Geslacht} van {Leeftijd} jaar oud.";
        }
    }
```

Main code

```
 public partial class Vijver : Form
    {
        private Random rnd = new Random();

        List<Kikker> kikkers2Kikkers = new List<Kikker>();
        Kikker Kikker1 = new Kikker("Frank", "Man", 2);
        Kikker Kikker2 = new Kikker("John", "Man", 1);

        Ooievaar ooievaar1 = new Ooievaar("Britt", "vrouw", 2, 50);
        public Vijver()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Kikkers2Kikkers.add(Kikker1);
            Kikkers2Kikkers.add(Kikker2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you've not added your `Kikker`s to your `kikkers2Kikkers`, so removing them will be difficult...

Comment: Which part are you stuck on - finding a random number or removing it?

Comment: i want the method "eetkikker" to remove a frog from the list

Comment: @ImSleepless Sure - there's two steps - finding a random index number between 0 and N-1, and then deleting the item at that index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Kikker> kikkers2Kikkers = new List<Kikker>();

            Kikker Kikker1 = new Kikker("Frank", "Man", 2);
            Kikker Kikker2 = new Kikker("John", "Man", 1);

            Ooievaar ooievaar1 = new Ooievaar("Britt", "vrouw", 2, 50);

            //add the kikkers to the list
            kikkers2Kikkers.Add(Kikker1);
            kikkers2Kikkers.Add(Kikker2);

            //random number
            Random rnd = new Random();
            var rndNumber = rnd.Next(0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(rndNumber); 

            //calling Eatkikker
            string deadKikker = ooievaar1.EetKikker(kikkers2Kikkers, rndNumber);

            //Rip kikker
            Console.WriteLine("Byebye " + kikkers2Kikkers.ElementAt(rndNumber));

            //remove dead kikker from list
            kikkers2Kikkers.RemoveAt(rndNumber);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

And the Ooievaar class with the EatKikker method:

class Ooievaar : Dier
{
    private int GegetenKikkers;

```
public Ooievaar(string naam, string geslacht, int leeftijd, int gegetenKikkers) : base(naam, geslacht, leeftijd)
{
    GegetenKikkers = gegetenKikkers;
}

public string EetKikker(List<Kikker> kikker, int rndNumber)
{
    //get the right kikker
    Kikker getKikker = kikker.ElementAt(rndNumber);
    //return a string
    return "Hello my name is " + getKikker.Naamdier + " and I am dead.";
}
```

}

Keep in mind that there is no exception handling for example `IndexOutOfRangeException`. `rnd.Next(0, 2);` is generating either 0 or 1. `Remove.At` requires `using System.Linq`.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to remove a item you'll use the remove method.
[Microsoft Documentation List .Remove(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.8).

```
Kikkers2Kikkers.Remove(Kikker1); // this will remove Kikker1 out of the list
```

If you want to make this random you should use RemoveAt and in the paramters at the index you want to remove.
[Microsoft Documentation Random Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8). You can easily get random values by using this class.

```
Random rnd = new Random(); //Create random object
int index = rnd.Next(Kikkers2Kikkers.Count); //Get value possible from your list
Kikkers2Kikkers.RemoveAt(index); // Removes a kikker randomly
```

But this isn't the complete solution to your program. This should give you an idea tho on how to remove an object from a list randomly.

Edit: I would not try to delete it from your ooievaar class. I would make a method in your main code and call it

```
OoievaarEetKikker(Ooievaar ooiveraar, Kikker kikker){
    ooievaar.EetKikker(); // In the Ooievaar class just add 1 to eaten kikkers
    Kikkers2Kikkers.Remove(kikker); // This deletes the kikker. You could use the random method from above.
}
```